# Query posts based on parents attribute

Tags: query-posts, metabox, sql

This is the scenario:
I have multiple pages that all have a custom field named "Location"
Those pages all have child-pages with the custom field of "size_m2".

What I want is to do a normal meta_query to list all pages with let say  "size_m2 >= 55", but only if the parent page have "Location == Stockholm".

Do i need to use a custom SQL query for this? 
Or can I query for the parent_pages children, and when filter and "query" that query?

Comment: I would edit this Question to adjust grammar and spelling, but I don't understand: what is **`och`**? You can [edit] the Question whenever needed. English language errors are no problem, we can correct them, but if you use a Spell Checker in your browser, helps a lot ;)

Comment: @brasofilo "och" means "and" in Swedish, apparently.

Comment: you should use WP_Query, do not use raw sql queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have:

```
foreach post where A is true, that has a child where B is true
```

Which is actually:

```
foreach post where A is true
    that has a child where B is true
```

So this is not something you should be doing in 1 query. Instead you would need to do n queries where n= parentposts+1. 1 query to find the parents, and then a query for each parent to find the children.

Clearly this is not going to be fast.

## The Root Of The Problem

Your data structure is inappropriate. You've attempted to do is reinvent taxonomies using post meta.

Instead, create a custom taxonomy called 'Location', and create a Stockholm term. Then do a query for all posts that have the meta for size, and add `'Location' => 'Stockholm'`.

Benefits:

- Querying is dramatically simplified
- You're given a working, extensively tested admin interface for free
- Its fast
- You get free archives, e.g. example.com/location/stockholm/
- Tight integration into the template heirarchy with new templates: `taxonomy.php`, `taxonomy-location.php` and even `taxonomy-location-stockholm.php`

Disadvantages:

- None
- Nothing
- There aren't any

As a sidenote, if you run into a situation where you need to execute an sql query, you've done something wrong.

Comment: The problem is that cause of limitations to my setup i cant place the child pages in a texonomy, can I query for all post in a taxonomy, including the children, and then filter by meta?

Comment: taxonomies can be applied to pages too, and there's nothing stopping you writing a snippet of code to run once that creates and assigns appropriate terms. I cannot think of a single instance you would not be able to use taxonomies that allows you to be able to modify the code.

Comment: And yes, you can query all posts in a taxonomy. I suspect your understanding of what a taxonomy is, is incomplete. e.g. a category is a taxonomy, the 'wordpress' category is a term in the category taxonomy. Tags are a taxonomy, a tag is a term in the tags taxonomy.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I have a heavily modified WordPress admin setup where i have divided pages with a custom tax, to make what I call "subposttypes" So that i can separate content, just like Custom Posttypes, but they all share the root slug. So I cant share the location tax with the children, it will mess stuff up, but thanks for taking time and helping me out!

Comment: So basically you're unaware of the rewrite option when registering taxonomies and post types, and implemented a complicated system of 'sub post types' that attempts to recreate it?

Comment: That's pretty vital information for your question, you should have mentioned it ( and your data structure must be a nightmare to maintain )

Comment: I have never been able to in stabel way remove the slug of a custom posttype to make em act exactly like pages.
url.com/pagename/subpagename and have the structure url.com/posttyppename/posttypechild work a long side.

But i whould love to know it this is indeed possible?

Comment: That's a new question, and one that's asked roughly every 2 weeks by someone or someone else

Comment: And the answer to that q is??: No Not Really possible in any stable form.. 
So that's way i created "sub-posttypes" to cater to a very spacial need form a client..  
And if you yourself don't have a solution, at-least don't be rube about it..

Comment: It would not be appropriate for me to answer such a question in comments, go search for it or ask a new question, after all you are on a Q&A site. And I do have a solution, taxonomies, custom post types, and a better SEO friendly URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a subquery on a post's parent using `WP_Query`, unfortunately. You could of course run 2 separate WP_Queries, using PHP to apply the results of the first (on the parent) to the `WHERE` of the second (the child).

However, I would just do a custom query using [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).